# How to update the timeFieldName in index Pattern in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, search, kibana, kibana-6

I am trying to update the timeField for a index pattern using the below code but I am getting an document missing exception. I have fetched correct id from the Index patterns URL. Could someone guide me how to update this.

```
POST /{_index}/_update/{_id}/ 
{ "doc": 
     { "index-pattern": 
         { "timeFieldName" : "{NEW_FIELD_NAME}" } 
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to prefix the id with `index-pattern:<id>`, like below:

```
POST /{_index}/_update/index-pattern:{_id}/ 
{ "doc": 
     { "index-pattern": 
         { "timeFieldName" : "{NEW_FIELD_NAME}" } 
     } 
}
```